# issue with PHP on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis

So I've done a bunch of research and tried a bunch of things that it'll be difficult to try and explain everything i've already done but here's my issue.

My website isn't interpreting PHP code, whether I try to use an include 'file.php'; or just input the code directly into the HTML it doesn't matter.

I'm running Windows 7 with IIS 7.5 with PHP installed from php.iis.net. I'm going to keep it simple rather than go into the specifics of exactly what I'm trying to do, and hopefully once I get the simple things working the more complex stuff I'm working on will work.

Here's the HTML piece:

```
Weather condition is currently <?php echo '<p>Hello world</p>'; ?>
```

The output is

> > Weather condition is currently Hello world 
> > '; ?>

The beginning bracket of the PHP is hidden, after World its showing the rest on a new line under the text.

I also have

```
<?php

phpinfo();

phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```

That returns nothing on the webpage, and if you look at the source code you see the full PHP code. Same with the Hello world example, the text doesn't show the ?php portion but viewing the page source you see the full php.

There's something I'm missing somewhere in the IIS config or the PHP config and I'm just not finding it.

Any insights or ideas I'm open to try. This is a fresh IIS and fresh PHP install, I installed IIS on this workstation specifically to get this PHP script to work so it is doing nothing else but hosting this web page.

thanks!

Comment: `and if you look at the source code you see the full PHP code` That simply means your IIS is not yet configured to work with the PHP interpreter for PHP pages. Did you go though this process? http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php

Comment: Not that one exactly but I'll go through it now. Though I finally was able to get a phpinfo() loaded by running it in index.php as the first thing loaded on the web page, but it still isn't interpreting in the actual HTML. Is my webpage supposed to be loaded from an index.php file? Is that what I'm missing? I feel like it's something so simple that I'm just too blind to see. Anyway I'll go through your list make sure I didn't miss anything.

Comment: So same result. I got the phpinfo.php file to load when directing the browser, but the code snippets I put in above still do not work when placed into the HTML.

Comment: Well holy freaking crap. So it appears the problem was I was running my HTML code from an HTML file. My newb butt didn't realize I actually needed to be running it from a PHP file. I moved all my HTML code to a .php file and am opening that from the web browser and now it appears to work. Your link was the only one I found where it had me actually open specifically a PHP file, none of the other sites I visited explicitly said "hey, dummy, open your HTML files in a php document". NewbsRMe over here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do I give you a thumbs up since you led me to the answer?

Comment: Cheers, enjoy programming now. If I posted it as an answer you could have given me an up-vote but since I only gave you a link to follow it isn't really an answer to a specific problem. So a cheers will do for now :)